# numpy select range in advanced indexing

Tags: python, numpy

I have two arrays that are used as indices

```
a = np.array([0, 5, 11])
b = np.array([2, 8, 13])
```

How can I select the range between these arrays? i.e. 0 - 2, 5 - 8, 11 - 13

```
c = np.array([0,1,2,5,6,7,8,11,12,13])
```

so that I can use

```
data[c] # selects all the elements between ranges a and b
```

How do I construct array `c`? I'm looking for a numpy solution

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> x = np.arange(20)
>>> a = [0, 5, 11]
>>> b = [2, 8, 13]
>>> np.hstack(x[start:stop+1] for start, stop in zip(a, b))
array([ 0,  1,  2,  5,  6,  7,  8, 11, 12, 13])
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> zip(a, b)
[(0, 2), (5, 8), (11, 13)]

>>> [range(l,h+1) for l,h in zip(a, b)]
[[0, 1, 2], [5, 6, 7, 8], [11, 12, 13]]

>>> list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(range(l,h+1) for l,h in zip(a, b)))
[0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 11, 12, 13]
```